# FLVPlayback skin modification problem in Adobe Flash CS5 with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, skinning, flvplayback, flash-cs5

I have been working on modifying an existing FLVPlayback skin.  Ideally I would like to have one that uses a counter.

The problem is, all the fla's provided for the skins with counters fail to publish/compile correctly. Fla's are here: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration\FLVPlayback Skins\FLA\ActionScript 3.0

I do end up with a swf, but it doesnt' work when applied to my FLVPlayback instance on the stage.  (All skin fla's beggining with 'Minima' do not work, even the skins without the counters)

I get the following warning when publishing: Warning: unable to load SWC FLVPlaybackAS2.swc

If I go to 'File -> Publish Settings -> Flash -> Settings', FLVPlaybackAS2.swc is not in my Library Path.   So, I added it... (C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration\Components\Video\FLVPlaybackAS2.swc)  But I get the exact same warning.

It seems strange to me that it would throw a warning about FLVPlaybackAS2.swc... this is an AS3 fla provided by Adobe. I also tried adding FLVPlaybackAS2.swc, FLVPlaybackAS3.swc, FLVPlaybackAS3_2.5.swc etc, with no change.

Another developer here has tried also and come up with the same problem.  We are both on PC's and have all Adobe updates.

Anyone have any ideas?!

Thanks,
James.

Comment: Didn't worked for me, I solved it by coping fl folder to my skin directory (fl folder is located in same directory where rest of the skin source files..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys... I found answer !  Just remove all from your source paths in the publish settings when you look to ActionScript 3.0 setting for your Skin FLA ! ( as default you can see here some path to video folder where is SWC files)

it's look like a bug but i did it and now my skin working.. now in this lines are empty field in my FLA..

if you want ask me and i will answer how it works.. good luck with this strange bug !